# Does this statistical distance have a name and does the triangle inequality hold?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, metric

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two distributions on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Define their distance by $$d(P, Q)=\Pr_{X\sim P,Y\sim Q}[P(X)Q(Y)>P(Y)Q(X)]\,,$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I could show that $d(P,Q)=d(Q,P)$ and $d(P,Q)\iff P=Q$. Simulation results suggest that the triangle inequality seems to hold.

I have two questions:

- Does this statistical distance have a name?
- Does the triangle inequality hold so that it is indeed a metric?

Comment: Please clarify what kind of quantities $P$ and $Q$ might be: probability masses?  Probability distribution functions?  Some form of generating functions, perhaps (to be imaginative, perhaps, but to illustrate the vagueness of the question)?  And shall we presume you mean they are *probability* distributions and not more general distributions?

Comment: @whuber $P$ and $Q$ are two distributions on natural numbers so they are probability masses.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Please note that it was needed: after all, probability masses are a special way to specify distributions.  Ways that work for *all* distributions include the CDF, the characteristic function, and its logarithm.  Thus, it's arguably more natural to assume that the term "distribution" when used as a function refers to the CDF no matter what--and many authors adopt that convention.